# SQL Server 2016 Get Max Date Within 14 Days

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, Users and WebSessions which are linked via a foreign key, UserId.  Each time a user logs in a new row in WebSessions is created.  The WebSessions table has a column called Created which is a DATETIME2.  I would like a query that selects all UserIds where the most recent WebSession was 76 days ago.  I have tried a few queries:

```
SELECT UserId, MAX(Created) AS LastAccess
FROM WebSessions
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, LastAccess, GETDATE()) > 16
```

This results in: Invalid column name 'LastAccess'

I also tried:

```
SELECT UserId, MAX(Created) AS LastAccess
FROM WebSessions 
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, (SELECT MAX(Created) FROM WebSessions GROUP BY UserId), GETDATE()) > 16
GROUP BY UserId
```

This results in: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: What does 76 days ago have to do with the query?  Why are you using inequality if you want exactly 76 days?  And why does the title say "14" if the queries have "16"?

Comment: simply cast datetime2 column as date

Comment: 16 days ago or 76 days ago ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT UserId, MAX(Created) AS LastAccess
FROM WebSessions
WHERE LastAccess >= DATEADD(day, -16, GETDATE())
GROUP BY UserId;
```

Your error message doesn't really make sense, but the first query is missing the `GROUP BY`.

In addition, I changed the date logic so the `WHERE` clause can make use of an index.

I suspect `LastAccess` is in the users table.  If so you need a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT u.UserId, MAX(ws.Created) AS LastAccess
FROM Users u JOIN
     WebSessions ws
     ON ws.UserId = u.UserId
WHERE ws.LastAccess >= DATEADD(day, -16, GETDATE())
GROUP BY u.UserId;
```

If you want users where the most recent session is within the last 16 days, then you want a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT u.UserId, MAX(ws.Created) AS LastAccess
FROM Users u JOIN
     WebSessions ws
     ON ws.UserId = u.UserId
GROUP BY u.UserId
HAVING MAX(ws.LastAccess) >= DATEADD(day, -16, GETDATE());
```

If you want those who haven't had a session in the last 16 days, than change the `>=` to `<=`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon I ended up using a variation of the last query.  The overall goal of this exercise is to disable accounts after 90 days of inactivity, but send an email warning the user after 76.

I tried using the first query but I still got the 'Invalid column name' error.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT UserId, MAX(Created) AS LastAccess
    FROM WebSessions 
    WHERE DATEDIFF(day, (SELECT MAX(Created) FROM WebSessions GROUP BY UserId), GETDATE()) > 2016
    GROUP BY UserId
```